# Stack overflow error in minimax algorim

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow, minimax, minmax

Hi so I've recently started programming in java and I've set myself a task of making an AI for a tic tac toe game I've made
However the minmax algorithm is throwing a Stack Overflow error and I cant see in the error or the program where the problem is.

Here's the program:

```
public State minmax(boolean max, State currentState)
{
    if (currentState.getNull() == 0) {
        return currentState;
    }
    else {
        State[] successorStates = currentState.getSuccessorStates(aiPlayer);

        ArrayList<Integer> scoresTemp = new ArrayList<>();

        for (State state : successorStates) {
            scoresTemp.add(evaluate(aiPlayer, minmax(!max, state)));
        }

        Integer[] scores = (Integer[]) scoresTemp.toArray();

        if (max) {
            State maxState = successorStates[0];
            int maxScore = evaluate(aiPlayer, maxState);
            for (int score : scores) {
                if (scores[0] > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = score;
                    maxState = successorStates[score];
                }
            }
            return maxState;
        }
        else
        {
            State minState = successorStates[0];
            int minScore = evaluate(aiPlayer, minState);
            for (int score : scores) {
                if (scores[0] > minScore) {
                    minScore = score;
                }
            }
            return minState;
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the state which is the best move to make.

getNull() returns the amount of spaces left that can be played on.

getSuccesorStates(Player) returns all of the succeeding states of that state by making a new state of which contains the old moves and a new one of the Player.

evaluate() returns the value -1, 0 or 1 depending on a win, draw or loss in that state. None returns 0

edit:

```
public int getNull()
{
    int amount = 0;

    for (int x =0; x<9; x++)
    {
        if (getAllCells()[x]==null)
        {
            amount++;
        }
    }

    return amount;
}

public State[] getSuccessorStates(Player player)
{
    State[] states = new State[getNull()];

    Player[][] stateCells = cells.clone();
    int[][] nullPositions = getNulls();

    for (int x=0; x<getNull(); x++)
    {
        stateCells[nullPositions[x][0]][nullPositions[x][1]] = player;
        states[x] = new State(player, stateCells);
        stateCells = cells.clone();
    }

    return states;
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:23)
    at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
    at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
    .
    .
    .
```

23: `if (currentState.getNull() == 0)`
32: `scoresTemp.add(evaluate(aiPlayer, minmax(!max, state)));`

```
public Player[] getAllCells()
{
    Player[] cellList = new Player[9];
    for (int x = 0; x<3; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y<3; y++)
        {
            cellList[y*3+x] = cells[x][y];
        }
    }
    return cellList;
}
```

minmax is called in:

```
public Ply getPly(State state)
{
    State bestState = minmax(true, state);
    State[] successorStates = state.getSuccessorStates(aiPlayer);
    ArrayList<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
    for (int x=0; x<successorStates.length; x++)
    {
        states.add(successorStates[x]);
    }
    int[][] nulls = state.getNulls();

    Ply bestPly = new Ply(aiPlayer, nulls[states.indexOf(bestState)][0], nulls[states.indexOf(bestState)][1]);

    return bestPly;
}
```

Thankyou if anyone could help:)

Comment: Where's your recursion? Which lines are involved in the SO exception?

Comment: Please include your code for `State.getNull()` and `State.getSuccessorStates(Player)`

Comment: This looks like a possible spot: `scoresTemp.add(evaluate(aiPlayer, minmax(!max, state)));`

Comment: added them, thanks

Comment: at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:23)
 at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
 at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
 at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
 at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32)
 at sample.AI.minmax(AI.java:32) and on and on and on...

Comment: if (currentState.getNull() == 0) {

Comment: scoresTemp.add(evaluate(aiPlayer, minmax(!max, state)));

Comment: Please edit your question and include this important information in the question proper.

Comment: and show `getAllCells(...)`.

Comment: Done, thankyou for the advice. It's my first time

Comment: Where is `minmax(...)` first called?

Comment: Put some `print` statements in your code (especially at the beginning of your functions) and see what happens as the program runs. I am sure it will help you greatly.

Comment: thanks for the advice, sudo, ill put them to check what im putting into lines 23 and 32 and some other parts

Comment: Note, when responding to someone's comment, append an `@` in front of their stackoverflow name, e.g., `@sudomakeinstall2`. This will notify that person that you've posted a comment for them.

Comment: Thankyou @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

scoresTemp.add(evaluate(aiPlayer, **minmax**(!max, state)));

When you call the minmax method you create a bunch of data that uses up the memory ( java allows a certain amount of the computers memory to be used ).
You then inside minmax call minmax again making it create even more data and this is happening infinitely until there is no more memory left and Java throws the StackOverflow exception.